# How to get first sub element which do not have text between them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a WYSIWYG editor called **[KindEditor](http://kindeditor.net/demo.php)**. I found that sometimes it will add an extra `<br>` automatically. I want to know how to remove the redundant `<br>` using jQuery.

For example, in the code blocks below, I want to remove the first `<br>` in Code block A and Code block B, and reserve it in Code block C.

**Code block A**

```
<p>
  <br> <!-- it's useless now; need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

**Code block B**

```
<p>

  <br> <!-- it's also useless now because the text before it's empty; need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

**Code block C**

```
<p>
  New Taipei City
  <br> <!-- The content before it is not empty, so it's useful; can not be removed -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

I want to use jQuery to do it, and I wrote a select as below:

```
$("p > br:first-child")
```

But it will also remove `<br>` in Code block C, so how can I do it using a jQuery selector?

Although we can do it using regex, I want to do it in jQuery.

Comment: One way could be using some RegEx  in the `.html()` content of each `p` and update it.

Comment: @Fecosos Yeah,but I am wonder if we can use `jQuery` to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` to check if the previous node is empty.

```js
//console.log($("p > br:first-child"))

$('p > br:first-child').filter(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.wholeText.trim() == "";
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <br> <!-- it's useless now,need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>


<p>

  <br> <!-- it's also useless now due to the text before it's empty,need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>


<p>
  New Taipei City
  <br> <!-- The content before it is not empty,so it's useful,can not be removed -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all whitespace inside the `p` and remove `br`'s only if are at the beginning of the `p`.

```
$("p").each(function(){
  var trimmedPText = $(this).html().trim();
  if(trimmedPText.indexOf("<br") == 0){
    $(this).children()[0].remove();
  }
});
```

I used `trimmedPText.indexOf('<br')` so it will match `<br>`, `<br/>`, or `<br />`. There could be a boost in performance by using RegEx instead of this, maybe.

Comment: I have found Sam's answer is more simple,thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet this is not the complete answer to your question but the starting point or logic in a way to acheive your goal.

Below code just first first element of p. Now do logic to find whether it is br tag or string then remove br.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "p" ).each(function( index ) {
      var elem = $(this).contents().eq(0).text();
      console.log(elem);
      // Now here check if it is br then remove br
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <br> <!-- it's useless now,need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>

<p>
  <br> <!-- it's also useless now due to the text before it's empty,need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>

<p>
  New Taipei City
  <br> <!-- The content before it is not empty,so it's useful,can not be removed -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also. Wrap text between special characters and check if its null or not.

### JS

```
var original = $("p").html();
$("p").prepend(":");
$("p > br:first-child").before(";");
var str = $("p").html();
var Strin = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(":")+1,str.lastIndexOf(";"));
$("p").html(original);
if(Strin.trim() == ""){
$("p > br:first-child").remove();
}
$("p").html();
```

### HTML

```
<p>
  New Taipei City
  <br> 
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/116799/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
<p>
  <br> <!-- it's useless now,need to remove -->
  Taiwan next
  <br>
  Taichung goes global!
</p>
<div id='test'>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
var final = ''
    if ($("p").html().trim().indexOf("<br>") == 0) {
    final = $("p").html().replace('<br>','');
  } else {
    final = $("p").html();
  }
  console.log(final);
  $("#test").html(final);
});
```